# big circle in math mode

Tags: symbols, circles

[image]

I want to make a big circle as shown above, so that students can fill up an inequality or equality sign. I tried `\fullmoon`, but it wasn't big enough. How can I make a big circle?

Comment: @Andrew I see no benefit in an MWE, here. The asker has clearly shown what they're looking for, and clearly stated what they've tried. This isn't a debugging question, so we have no use for the asker's non-working code. Further, the absence of an MWE didn't seem to hinder you or another user from answering the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby TeX.SX is not a "draw this for me" site, so one advantage of a MWE is that it shows that the person asking the question has made an effort. At a minimum, a MWE also provides the "surrounding" code for people to work with, and so makes it easier for people to answer the question rather than having to waste time finding the requisite packages, such as  [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for the `\frac` command. I agree that everything is pretty trivial in this case but, even so, I'd like to see a MWE.

Comment: @Andrew You don't need amsmath for `\frac` and "I tried `\fullmoon`" already demonstrates that the asker made an effort.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Probably @Andrew meant `\usepackage{wasysym}` for `\fullmoon`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [MnSymbol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/MnSymbol) package provides a `\bigcircle` command, however, it is a little smaller than you want. You can use `\scalebox` from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to make the circle a little bigger. It is still a little high, so `\raisebox` can be used to adjust this. Putting this together into a macro:

```
\newcommand\Bigcircle{\raisebox{-0.5mm}{\scalebox{1.7}{$\bigcircle$}}}
```

produces:

[image]

Another, arguably more flexible, approach is to use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to draw the circle. Again, you need to adjust the baseline of the circle, but it is much easier to change the size of the circle and the width of line. It is also very easy to draw other shapes, such as squares, this way. The macro

```
\newcommand\TikCircle[1][2.5]{\tikz[baseline=-#1]{\draw[thick](0,0)circle[radius=#1mm];}}
```

shows one way of doing it this way to use tikz. (The `\TikCircle` command takes an optional argument that gives the radius of the circle in milimeters. By default, the radius is `2.5mm` so `\TikCircle` is the same as `\TikCircle[2.5]`.) This produces:

[image]

Here is the full code as a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% mnsymbol approach
\usepackage{MnSymbol,graphicx}
\newcommand\Bigcircle{\raisebox{-0.5mm}{\scalebox{1.7}{$\bigcircle$}}}

% tikz approach
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\TikCircle[1][2.5]{\tikz[baseline=-#1]{\draw[thick](0,0)circle[radius=#1mm];}}

\begin{document}

    MnSymbol:\bigskip

    $\frac34 \Bigcircle\frac14$

    \bigskip

    Tikz:\bigskip

    $\frac34 \TikCircle\frac14$

\end{document}
```

Finally, you probably want to add some space around these symbols. I would treat these as "mathematics operators" and use `\mathop`:

```
\newcommand\TikCircle[1][2.5]{{\mathop{\tikz[baseline=-#1]{\draw[thick](0,0)circle[radius=#1mm];}}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about using a "traditional" square instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fillrel}{\mathrel{\fbox{$\phantom{\bigcirc}$}}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{3}{4} \fillrel \frac{1}{2} \fillrel \frac{5}{10}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I like squares more than circles, but I wanted consistency with other resources I am using.